# Laravel 5.1 @can, how use OR clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I did not find how to use a clause (OR, AND) in view with @can, for checking multiple abilities ...

I tried:

```
@can(['permission1', 'permission2']) 
@can('permission1' or 'permission2')
@can('permission1' || 'permission2')
```

But dont work ;(

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the Gate facade:

```
@if(Gate::check('permission1') || Gate::check('permission2'))

@endif
```

Comment: Is there difference from @can and this way? in this case, wich?

Answer (score 52):

The @canany blade directive has been added to [Laravel v.5.6.23](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/CHANGELOG-5.6.md#v5623-2018-05-24) on May 24, 2018

Usage:

```
@canany(['edit posts', 'delete posts'])
    <div class="actions">
        @can('edit posts')
            <button>Edit post</button>
        @endcan
        @can('delete posts')
            <button>Delete post</button>
        @endcan
    </div>
@endcanany
```

Comment: Do you know if @ canany supports passing the policy model? For example with @ can you can do @ can('edit', 'App\Post').

Comment: @ScottSalisbury you can use e.g. `@canany(['post.update', 'post.create'], [$post])` But it's not ideal since it's the same argument for both policies. I would recommend to make your own directive for the example I provided.

Answer (score 8):

I've added this directive in my Laravel 5.4 app that allows me to use a new `@canany('write|delete')` directive in my blade views.

```
// AppServiceProvider.php@boot()

Blade::directive('canany', function ($arguments) {
    list($permissions, $guard) = explode(',', $arguments.',');

    $permissions = explode('|', str_replace('\'', '', $permissions));

    $expression = "<?php if(auth({$guard})->check() && ( false";
    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        $expression .= " || auth({$guard})->user()->can('{$permission}')";
    }

    return $expression . ")): ?>";
});

Blade::directive('endcanany', function () {
    return '<?php endif; ?>';
});
```

Example in blade view:

```
@canany('write|create')
    ...
@endcanany
```

Here's the [doc for extending Blade on 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade)

Comment: Very nice!  This should be in Laravel core.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `@can` multiple times.

<del>@if( @can('permission1') || @can('permission2') )</del>

```
@if( Gate::check('permission1') || Gate::check('permission2') )
```

Comment: @Marcaum54 What about it doesn't work? Does it give an error?

Comment: Follow error:

FatalErrorException in /.../0681985e98a64fda6c3db7d157508293 line 53:
**Call to undefined function can()**

when generating the view he returned this:

<?php if( @can('inscricoes') ||  @can('inscricoes-opec') ): ?>

Comment: This compiles to `<?php if(@can('permission1') || @can('permission2')): ?>`. Note that `@can()` is a valid function call (the at-symbol suppresses warnings), but the can() method does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using laravel  `spatie package` , then you can do it easily by following way..

> Using hasAnyPermission() method

```
@if(auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['permission1','permission2']))
   // statements 
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `can` method on `Authenticated User`,

```
@if ( Auth::user()->can('permission1', App\Model::class) || Auth::user()->can('permission2',  App\Model::class) )

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

@if(Gate::check('manage-users') || Gate::check('add-new-user'))
Manage Users

```
    <li>
      <a href="{{url('/back/users')}}">
        <i class="feather icon-users"></i>
       <span class="menu-item" data-i18n="users">Manage Users</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

@endif

Answer (score -1):

just use @canany(['permision1','permision2'])

Comment: Please, don't post code without an explanation as an answer. Try to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.