# laravel/ how to check a permissions in blade and controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I create some permissions and roles for my laravel project.

in `web.php` route, I can define a middleware like this with some permissions:

```
$can = ['can:manage_global,manage_users,create_users'];
$this->get('/create', 'UserController@create')->middleware($can);
```

or in blade with one permission:

```
@can('manage_global')
   ...
@endcan
```

How can I check multi permission values in blade and controller line `web.php`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188461/laravel-5-1-can-how-use-or-clause

Comment: @Roman Bobrik thanks. how about in controller?

Comment: if i understood you correctly, try that https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#controller-middleware

Comment: Are you trying to check multi-permissions in your blade file AND in your controller, like you can in your web routes? Is that what I'm understanding? (Also, which version of Laravel are you using?)

Answer (score 2):

You can write middleware.

```
class CanAnyMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permissions)
    {
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            if ( $request->user()->can($permission)) {
                return $next($request); // allow
            }
        }

        return redirect(route('home')); // deny
    }
}
```

And use it in route string.

```
Route::get('/create', 'UserController@create')
    ->middleware('canAny:manage_global,manage_users,create_users');
```

And since Laravel 5.6 you can use `@canany` in Blade:

```
@canany(['manage_global', 'manage_users', 'create_users'])
    ...
@endcanany
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24137

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check if a user can access any of your defined gates, from the controller, you can take a queue from the existing [Authorizable trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/Authorizable.php) and add some additional functionality in your own trait.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits\MyAuthorizable;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;

trait MyAuthorizable {
  public function canAny(array $abilities, $arguments = []) {
    return collect($abilities)->reduce(function($canAccess, $ability) use ($arguments) {
      // if this user has access to any of the previously checked abilities, or the current ability, return true
      return $canAccess || app(Gate::class)->forUser($this)->check($ability, $arguments);
    }, false);
  }

  public function canAll(array $abilities, $arguments = []) {
    return collect($abilities)->reduce(function($canAccess, $ability) use ($arguments) {
      // if this user has access to _all_ of the previously checked abilities, _and_ the current ability, return true
      return $canAccess && app(Gate::class)->forUser($this)->check($ability, $arguments);
    }, true);
  }
}
```

You can than add this trait to your user class with `use App\ MyAuthorizable;` in your user class definition.

This will expose the `canAny` and `canAll` methods for your user, which you can then access from your controller.

```php
<?php

public function get($request) {
    $User = Auth::User();

    if ($User->canAll(['manage_global', 'manage_users', 'create_users'])) {
        // user can do all of the things
    } elseif ($User->canAny(['manage_global', 'manage_users', 'create_users']) {
        // user can only do _some_ of the things
    } else {
        // user can do _none_ of the things
    }
}
```